# How do I change my windows xp password from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, command-line

How do I change my windows xp password from the command line? I tried password/passwd etc. commands but none of them exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [webpage](http://www.askstudent.com/hacking/how-to-change-your-windows-password-using-the-command-line/) for how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> net user USERNAME PASSWORD /DOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

A better one (Invisible bash-login like password prompt) will be:

```
net user USERNAME *
```